# How to open popup with the values recivied from Ajax

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML code

```
<a href="#openModal" id="myancor">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openthispopup" class="modalDialog">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Modal Box</h2>
      <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
      <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

and on click of a button i am trying to show popup and i tried it this way

```
$("#myancor").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_url',
        type: 'form_method',
        data: 'form_data',
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml) {
            $('#openthispopup').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Could you please tell me how to pop up from Ajax success call

This is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/61ky7h2m/18/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#openthispopup').modal('show');
```

to

```
$('#openthispopup').css('opacity',1);
```

should do the trick

**EDIT**

This should do what you want.

```
$(".close").click(function() {
    $('#openthispopup').css('opacity',0);
});
$("#myancor").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_url',
        type: 'form_method',
        data: 'form_data',
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml) {
            $('#openthispopup').css('opacity',1);
        }
    });
});
```

For dialogs without a close button, use:

```
$("html")
```

instead of:

```
$(".close")
```

Comment: This works great and could you please tell me how to close it when clicked on cross mark ??

Comment: $('#openthispopup').css('opacity',0);

Comment: To be a little more jQuery friendly and actually use the animation queue:
Change `opacity:0` in the CSS to `display:none` and then use `$('#openthispopup').fadeIn('slow');` in the JavaScript to open the dialog.
Close the dialog box by listening for a click, in this example any click will do:
`$("html").click(function() {
 $("#openthispopup").fadeOut("slow")
});`